Proving that cylinder-to-sphere projection is area preserving.
I was going through the textbook Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice, and in the chapter for light, it talks about how the projection from a cylinder to sphere is area-preserving. I was trying to solve exercise 26.1 and I got as far as finding the Jacobian Matrix for the mapping, however when I tried to find the determinant, the determinant I got was 0 so I am very confused.
Projection given by the notebook
Exercise 26.1: We claimed in the chapter that the horizontal projection P to the
unit sphere from the vertical cylinder enclosing it was an area-preserving map.
Compute the derivative of this map at a point (x, y, 0) of the cylinder, and verify
that it is area-preserving. Why is it sufficient to carry out this computation at a
point where z = 0?
Thank you!

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

You need to compute the Jacobian of the mapping of surfaces. Write the mapping using cylindrical coordinates and spherical coordinates to start with.

Welcome to MSE! <> Searching for "Archimedes hat box theorem" (at MSE, or generally on the web) may be helpful. Separately, there's a diagram here.
